# How to split PHP CI model functions into multiple 'include' files

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I have the following Code Igniter web service Model that my Controller calls.  This Model has about 30 functions in it.

I would like to split up the functions in the Model to be in separate files so that it's easier for multiple people to work on them, although it's not possible to 'include' a file outside of a function like this:

```
class Webservice_model extends CI_Model{

    include 'function/login.php';
    include 'function/register.php';
    include 'function/checkin.php';

    // etc etc x 10
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?  Without having to do this:

```
class Webservice_model extends CI_Model{

    function login(){
        // login functionality
    }
    function register(){
        // register functionality
    }
    function checkin(){
        // checkin functionality
    } 

    // etc etc x 10
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is create different models i.e. different files for each model

example model 1: Login_model.php
2. Register_model.php
3. Checkin_model.php

And then call them in model like

```
class Webservice_model extends CI_model{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('login_model');
    $CI->load->model('register_model');
    $CI->load->model('checkin_model');

}
```

}

In this way different people can work on different functions

Comment: Hi @Kailas, it seems like all the functions in these models are being called when i try to load the Controller index webpage.  The page doesn't load to show the Controllers, it is instead showing errors in my Models.  

Do you know if CodeIgniter is calling these Model functions or just checking them for errors?  It seems like it's actually calling them when i load the models (like in your code above).

Comment: hi,  I checked all functionality and it worked fine .only notes are : 1.Keep  first letter of model file name capital, 2. load models in constructor as shown in my updated code.

Comment: Hi Kailas, yeah i worked that out, the naming convention sucks but apart from that it's all good :)  Thank you